# Finding R, C and Switching Frequency

Tags: switching

I need to find R,C and switching frequency of the following circuit such that  Switching Frequency is low as possible with given Vu and VL.

Also how can I improve the circuit so that it can reach it's output voltage quickly with good transient respond.

[image]

Comment: To make the circuit switch as quickly as possible you just need to remove the capacitor. That will also simplify your equations.

Comment: Mske the cap zero, and the resistors large, as well as the current source.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Current source is fixed (0.8A)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's current source

Comment: What do you mean "it's current source"? I'm talking about the thing on the right with the big letter "C" next to it. Take that out and you circuit will be really fast.

Answer (score 2):

> Too long for a comment.

Well, we know that when the switch is closed we get:

$$\text{i}_\text{s}\left(t\right)=\text{i}_\text{R}\left(t\right)+\text{i}_\text{C}\left(t\right)+\text{i}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Using the voltage and current relations in a resistor and capacitor we can rewrite equation \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$\text{i}_\text{s}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)+\text{C}\cdot\text{V}_\text{C}'\left(t\right)+\frac{1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}\cdot\text{V}_{\text{R}_\text{L}}\left(t\right)\tag2$$

Because this is a parallel circuit we know that all the voltages in equation \$(2)\$ are equal, so we can write:

$$\text{i}_\text{s}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\text{V}\left(t\right)+\text{C}\cdot\text{V}'\left(t\right)+\frac{1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}\cdot\text{V}\left(t\right)\tag3$$

Solving that DE with the given values and that the initial condition equal to \$0\$ gives:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=\frac{120\cdot\text{R}}{150+\text{R}}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{150+\text{R}}{150\cdot\text{C}\cdot\text{R}}\cdot t\right)\right)\tag4$$

And when the switch is open we get:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\text{R}\tag5$$

Comment: We need to find C and Switching frequency too!

Comment: @JugalMistry I've no idea how you can determine the frequency because if you have the value of the voltage when the switch is closed you have two values to take care of the C and the t (time).

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I am assuming time constant of the RC circuit to be very high and switch is ideal.
At steady state , the average voltage across the capacitor should be 5.4V, meaning that average charging and discharging rates should be equal. Also since the fluctuation of capacitor voltage needs to be \$\pm0.1\$, means that maximum voltage across capacitor is \$V_{C0} = 5.5V\$. And the current is given to be \$i=0.8A\$.
$$\Delta V_{Ton} = \Delta V_{Toff}$$
$$V_{C0}\frac{T_{off}}{R_LC} = (i(R||R_L)-V_{C0})\frac{T_{on}}{R||R_{L}C}$$
$$V_{C0}\frac{T_{off}}{R_LC} = 0.2$$
$$iR=7.2$$

1. The first equation equates the average voltage change in on and off
   state. In other words, average voltage loss during discharge is equal to the average voltage gain during charging.
2. For RC>> T (= Time Period of switching), exponential is approximated
   by its first order term in power series expansion and the voltage
   changes are given by the second equation.
3. The third equation equates the voltage change to twice the given amount of 0.1V because we are starting from the maximum instead of average.
4. Fourth equation comes because you want 7.2V maximum voltage around R which occurs when the switch is open and all the current flows through R.
   Solving these equations gives you \$T_{on}\$ and \$T_{off}\$ in terms of C, which are approximately given by,
   $$T_{on} \approx C$$
   $$T_{off} \approx 5C$$
   The actual value of the capacitor now depends on the switching frequency, so for instance if you choose T (= \$T_{on} + T_{off}\$) to be 6\$\mu s\$, then capacitor comes around 1\$\mu F\$.
   Lastly, we need to check if the approximation that the RC time constant is high compared to time period is valid or not. The smallest time constant of the capacitor comes around 54\$\mu s\$, which is much larger then the time period. So linear approximation should be valid.
   Just to confirm my calculations, I simulated this circuit in LTSpice and the following is the result:
   [image]

[image]

Here the blue waveform is the capacitor output voltage and the green waveform is the switching clock.
Clearly, the waveform is reaching average of 5.4V with maximum voltage of 5.5V as calculated. Also the waveforms appear linear because of large time constant of the circuit.